# Javascript to update text box when radio button are automatically checked

Tags: javascript

I am creating a set of radio buttons, that when checked, update a text box with all of the options checked. However, if you only select one of four options the remaining part of the text box will populate with 'undefined' for each remaining button that isn't clicked, which in this case would be three.

To try and avoid getting 'undefined' and show all the options in the text field at once I created a script that would automatically check the radio buttons after a certain time has passed. But, it doesn't update the text field as if I had clicked on the button. Any ideas?

Here's the code that checks them, and the code that puts them in the text field..

```
var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  
setTimeout(function() { 
  for (i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
    if (allElems[i].type == 'radio') {
        allElems[i].checked = true;
        }
    }   
}, 5000);

  $('input[name="o1"]').on('change', function() { 
    $('input[id="text-yui_3_17_2_1_1502294158679_90364-field"]').val($('input[name="o1"]:checked').val()+$('input[name="o2"]:checked').val()+$('input[name="o3"]:checked').val()+$('input[name="o4"]:checked').val());
});
```

Comment: Any reason for the `Timeout` wrapping the for loop?

Comment: It was a test to see that after the page was already loaded and then they became checked it would update the text box. But it behaves as if they were pre-checked upon loading the page.

Comment: If you are getting `undefined` then it's no doubt because your javascript is executing before the browser know of any existing elements you are trying to target/get.... you could always wrap that section in a DOM ready function `window.onload=function(){ //Here };` or you can move that script to the bottom of the page or below the elements you're trying to target. The browser reads like us, top > left > down... so order matters

Comment: I get undefined in the text area because if I make one selection it populates the text field as if all of them have been clicked. If only one gets clicked it goes from nothing in the field to 'Option 1, undefinedundefinedundefined.' If I load the page with buttons already checked, I still get an empty text field until I change one of the answers. I want the field pre populated with answers of the already checked boxes. Does this make sense? I tried 'window.onload' and nothing visually changed.